# why tcpdf library output one record from loop?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, tcpdf

i used TCPDF with codeigniter ,when PDF  generated from sql query i got one record in the pdf file ,however,the table has three records...

```
print_r($pdf_data);
```

gave me this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [no] => 1 [name] => Jamal [address] => ÙØ®Ø± ) [1] => Array ( [no] => 2 [name] => Jina [address] => Washington D.C ) [2] => Array ( [no] => 3 [name] => Dijandra [address] => Nairboi ) )
```

the controler

```
<?php

    class example extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('pdf');
        }

        function b() {
            $this->pdf->AddPage();
            $font1 = $this->pdf->addTTFfont(K_PATH_FONTS . 'arial.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 8);
            $this->pdf->SetFont($font1, '', 15, '', false);
            $this->load->model('member_model');
            $pdf_data = $this->member_model->alldata();
            foreach ($pdf_data as $rows) {

                $tbl = '<table style="width: 638px;" cellspacing="0">';
                $id = $rows['no'];
                $name = $rows['name'];
                $address = $rows['address'];

                $tbl .= '<tr>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 150px;">' . $id . '</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 378px;">' . $name . '</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 110px; text-align:center">' . $address . '</td>
                </tr>';

                $tbl .= '</table>';

                $this->pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
                  $this->pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
            }
        }
    ?>
```

the model

```
<?php

class Member_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function alldata() {
        $this->db->select('*')->from('tb_member')->order_by('no', 'ASC');
        $getData = $this->db->get();
        if ($getData->num_rows() > 0)
            return $getData->result_array();
        else
            return NULL;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From inside your `foreach` loop, remove the following segment:

```
$this->pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
```

And put it outside the loop body.

Comment: when i removed this line i got nothing.. no pdf generated

Comment: @user1080247 Did you put it just outside the `foreach` body?

Comment: please doctor can you help my why i see table like this image